# Date didn't passe to the Edit view how do i pass that in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

----My Controller---

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var dbContext = new MyDBDataContext();
        var userDetails = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(userId => userId.UserId == id);
        var user = new Management.Models.User();

        if (userDetails != null)
        { 
            user.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(userDetails.DOB);
            user.POS = Convert.ToDateTime( userDetails.POS); 
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

-----Model------

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter the Date that Start service")]
    [Display(Name = "Period Of Service")]
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd-mm-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime POS { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select the Date of birth")]
    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd-mm-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

---------View-------

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayName("Date Of Join")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.POS)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.POS)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary)
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What is `user.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(userDetails.DOB);` Are you seriously storing dates in the database as a string?

Comment: No,in mssql database its stored as an date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using `EditorFor` to generate the browsers datepicker (HTML5) then (note the format string)

```
Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter the Date that Start service")]
[Display(Name = "Period Of Service")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime POS { get; set; }
```

The value of `POS` will then be shown in the culture of the browser.

Comment: Thank you, its working but when i run it using firefox, it's didn't show the datepicker

Comment: No, `<input type="date" ..>` is still not supported in FireFox. [See comparison here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-34/opera-24.html). Its why jquery plugins are still currently best for datepickers.

Comment: Do you can tell me how to take period of service should appear in the following format: ## years, ## months. Both years and months should be zero-filled left justified, e.g. 05 years, 01 months. and the o Period of service is the time period from the date-of-join to Dec 31st, 2014.

Comment: AFAIK, you could not do that with the HTML5 datepicker. Its rendered by the browser and you have very little control over how it displays dates and it may well vary between browsers.

Comment: Do you can tell me how to take period of service should appear in the following format: ## years, ## months. Both years and months should be zero-filled left justified, e.g. 05 years, 01 months. and the o Period of service is the time period from the date-of-join to Dec 31st, 2014. join date can be take from "POS' from table